# Inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s)= e^{-s}\arctan\Big(\frac{s+4}{(s+4)^2+4}\Big)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I've tried applying theorems to remove $e^{-s}$ and change $(s+4)$ to $s$ but I don't know what to do with the resulting Inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Did you mean $$F(s)=e^{-s}\arctan\left(\frac{s+4}{(s+4)^2+4}\right)\Huge ?$$

Comment: CAS says: ${\it invlaplace} \left( {{\rm e}^{-s}}\arctan \left( {\frac {s+4}{
 \left( s+4 \right) ^{2}+4}} \right) ,s,t \right) =2\,{\frac {{\it 
Heaviside} \left( t-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-4\,t+4}}\sin \left( t/2-1/2
 \right) \cos \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {17} \left( t-1 \right)  \right) }{t-1
}}
$

Answer (score 2):

Once you've dealt with the time and frequency shifts, the problem reduces to finding the inverse transform of 
$$ G(s) = \arctan \left(\frac{s}{s^2+4}\right) $$

The $\arctan$ outer function might suggest you use the derivative property
$$ \mathcal L^{-1} \{G'(s)\} = -t g(t) $$

By the chain rule, we have

$$ G'(s) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{s^2}{(s^2+4)^2}}\frac{4-s^2}{(s^2+4)^2} = \frac{4-s^2}{(s^2+4)^2+s^2} = \frac{4-s^2}{s^4+9s^2+16} $$

The denominator here is a quadratic in $s^2$ with two roots: $\frac{-9\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}$. Since they are both negative we can write

$$ s^4 + 9s^2 +16 = \left(s^2+ \frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2} \right)\left(s^2+\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right) = (s^2+{a_1}^2)(s^2+{a_2}^2) $$

Applying partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{4-s^2}{(s^2+{a_1}^2)(s^2+{a_2}^2)} = \frac{As+B}{s^2+{a_1}^2} + \frac{Cs+D}{s^2+{a_2}^2} $$

You will quickly find $A=C=0$ since the LHS is an even function. The remaining two constants are up to you to solve.

Taking the inverse transform of $G'(s)$ gives

$$ g(t) = -\frac{B\sin(a_1 t)}{a_1t} -\frac{D\sin(a_2 t)}{a_2t} $$